How to access to workitems elements in Polarion using python
I'm trying to realize a python script that is able to get some info from Polarion.
I've made the connection and selected the path and the document.
I'd like to get the info I've circled in all the workitems:

So I was expecting that calling the function getWorkitems(), as written in the info, to get all complete workitems returned as a Workitem[]
document = project.getDocument('/Input Documents/Allegato 4 - Sottosistema MR')
workitem_getWorkitem=document.getWorkitems()

I'm getting the following error:
 raise exceptions.ValidationError(
zeep.exceptions.ValidationError: Missing element moduleURI (getModuleWorkItemUris.moduleURI)


The error message mentions that you have to provide the module URI which is the document URI. I assume that you use the web service as documented here: Polarion SDK Documentation.
If you want to follow the document based approach, you can do:
// Get all project folders
_connection.Tracker.GetWikiSpaces(projectId)

// Get all documents from a folder
_connection.Tracker.GetModules(projectId, folder)

// Get all workitems from a document
var workItemFields = new List<string> { "id", "title", "type", "description", "project",  ... };
_connection.Tracker.GetModuleWorkItems(document.uri, null, true, workItemFields.ToArray());

Since you already have provided the work item ID in your example: RLZ-840, you can as well query that item directly:
var workItemIdQuery = "RLZ-840";
_connection.Tracker.queryWorkItems(workItemIdQuery, "id", workItemFields.ToArray());

You highlighted some comments in your example, so you should extend the workItemFields list by that property name.
One side note: I suggest that you utilize the REST API, because the web service interface has been put in maintenance mode with Version 2404: 
